# Какие функции или методы есть для отслеживания касания экрана мобильного телефона?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Вы не могли бы подсказать как можно сделать, чтобы я мог нажать на две (условные) кнопки одновременно и чтобы эти кнопки выполняли сразу два действия?

Я делаю мобильную игру на python с использованием pygame и мне нужно узнать может ли pygame "увидеть", что я нажал двумя пальцами на разные кнопки одновременно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15700458/1597497), что Pygame напрямую не поддерживает мультитач и по существу ставит в очередь мультитач-взаимодействия как отдельные события мыши. Однако вы можете обойти систему событий мыши pygame и использовать библиотеку [touchpy](https://code.google.com/p/touchpy/) для обработки/перехвата сенсорного и мультитач-ввода. [Здесь](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/) можно увидеть серию руководств по решению именно этой проблемы (Части [1](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python/), [2](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python-part-2/), [3](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python-part-3/), [4](https://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/12/03/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python-part-4/)).